# Getting ids for newly created resource in Angular factory from server

Tags: javascript, mongodb, rest, angularjs

I am building an Angular app backed by a Node.js/Mongodb application.

The `id` for each resource is generated by Mongodb when a resource is created.

After I `POST` my new object to the server from a factory, the server returns a `201` response code with a location header set to the new resource's URI. How do I handle the response and then update the record with the correct `id`?

```
angular.module('myApp.Todoservices',['ngResource']).
factory('Todo',function($resource){
    return $resource('http://localhost\\:3000/todos/:id', {id:'@_id'}, {
        getAll: {method:'GET', isArray:true},
        update : {method:'PUT'},
        create : {method:'POST'},
        delete : {method:'DELETE'}
    });
});
```

Comment: Doesn't the server return with the newly created record too (in which you can find the ID of the newly created record)?

Comment: @callmekatootie As I understand it, the proper response is `201 Created` with a Location header pointing to the new resource. See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30. I'll edit my question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said earlier, this is not supported by `$resource`, I have no idea why. However, here is my workaround.

```
var tmpPart = new MyResource({name: $scope.item.name});
tmpPart.$create(function(_tmpPart, responseHeaders){
    $resource(responseHeaders("Location")).get(function(tempResourceObject){
        $scope.myResourceObjects.push(new MyResource(tempResourceObject))
    });
});
```

Where `new MyResource(tempResourceObject)` is a new instance of your resource object, you can do whatever you want with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can override default $resource service with custom one.
*sorry for coffeescript and ng-classify*

```
class Resource extends Factory
  constructor: ($resource, $http) ->
    return class ResourceFactory extends $resource
      constructor: (url, paramDefaults, actions, options)->
        class Res extends super
          $save: (params, success, error)=>
            super(
              params
            , (response, responseHeaders)=>
              if location = responseHeaders("Location")
                $http
                .get(location)
                .then (httpResponse)->
                  success new Res httpResponse.data, responseHeaders
                , error
              else
                success response, responseHeaders
            , error
            )

        return Res
```

After that

```
Users = Resource '/users'
user = new Users name:'foo'
user.$save (savedUser)->
  savedUser # will be created from data loaded from location header of post response
```

Answer (score 0):

$resource service is a high-level wrapper for the underlying $http service.

Success and Error callbacks of the $resource methods (`post()`, `put()`, `get()`, ...) receive a response object which contains a `headers()` method.

With this method you are able to either get an array of all response headers or, if you provide a specific header name as a parameter, get a specific header value:

```
var successCallback = function(response){
  var location = response.headers('location');
  // extract resource ID form the location header here...
}

$scope.todo.post(data, successCallback);
```

$http header getter function is described in [$http docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http#Returns)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like $resource (still) does not support that [1], so for now use $http [2] service.

[1] https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7037

[2] http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the "angular-resource": "1.3.11" and it looks quite simple. According with Angular resource documentation:

> The action methods on the class object or instance object can be
>   invoked with the following parameters:
>
> HTTP GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], [success],
>   [error])
>
> non-GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters],
>   postData, [success], [error])
>
> non-GET instance actions:
>   instance.$action([parameters], [success], [error])
>
> Success callback is
>   called with (value, responseHeaders) arguments.
>
> Error callback is called with (httpResponse) argument.

```
 todo.save(postData,
       function (value, responseHeaders) {
           $scope.id = responseHeaders('Location').split('/').pop();
       }
);
```